# Cannot destructure property "commands" of message.bot as it is undefined (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So, I was switching to module.exports for my bot and for the help command I got the error: "Cannot destructure property "commands" of message.bot as it is undefined"

I never experienced the error before so I don't know how to fix it.

Also I copied the advanced command handler code from the official discord.js guide and it still does not work.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
module.exports = {
    name: 'help',
    description: 'List all of my commands or info about a specific command.',
    aliases: ['commands'],
    usage: '!help | !help <command name>',
    cooldown: 1,
    async execute(message, args, bot) {
    const data = []
        const { commands } = message.bot;

if(!args[1]){

            let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle('Commands')
                .addField('Fun ', Wide)
                .addField('Games ', funay)
                .addField('Information ', inf)
                .addField(`Images `, imagess)
                .addField('Moderation ‍⚖️', mod)
                .addField('Giveaway', gib)
                .addField('Other', other)
                .setColor('RANDOM')
                .setThumbnail(message.author.displayAvatarURL())
        
            message.channel.send(embed)
} else {
const name = args[1].toLowerCase()
const cmd = commands.get(name) || commands.find(c => c.aliases && c.aliases.includes(name));
if (!cmd) {
            return message.reply('that\'s not a valid command!');
        }
  const embedd = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`Name: ${cmd.name}`)
    .addField('Aliases', `${cmd.aliases.join(", ")}`)
    .addField('Description', `${cmd.description}`)
      .addField('Usage', data.push `${cmd.usage}`)
        .setFooter(`Cooldown: ${cmd.cooldown || 3} second(s)`)
    .setColor("RANDOM")
        message.channel.send(embedd);
}
    },
}
```

Comment: The line `const { commands } = message.bot;` is erroring because message.bot is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change `message.bot` to `message.client`

Comment: That doesn't matter. There is no property called "bot" in the message object. Please read the [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message).